# Label Text is not wrapped

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I assign a label in a table view but the text in the label does not wrap to the next line when it is too long.

My code is follow:

```
UILabel *food_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
foodspe = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"food"]];
foodspe = [foodspe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
foodspe = [foodspe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
foodspe = [foodspe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
foodspe = [foodspe stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

food_lbl.text = foodspe;
food_lbl.numberOfLines=2;
food_lbl.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

[food_lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 150, 100)];
[food_lbl setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25.0f]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:header];
```

e.g. `food_lbl` is `paneer,panjabi,pasta,pizza,Puff,chocolates`

Comment: Have you tried setting the text after you have set up other options (lineBreakMode, etc.)?

Comment: NO,i am not setting another text

Comment: I'm asking you to try to swap `food_lbl.text = foodspe;` to the end.

Comment: how many words do you have in the text? what character does separate the words from each other?

Comment: words are generated dinamically & it is not wrap through word

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
food_lbl.numberOfLines=0;
```

Comment: i think your font size is too large to fit in the frame, try decreasing font size and increase frame

Comment: but what is relation bet font size & frame and word wrap

Comment: check your framewidth is 500 may be its out of iPhone screen bounds.

Comment: [food_lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 500, 100)];

Answer (score 0):

Go to the UILabel property in the xib and make Autoshrink YES.

Comment: Autoshrink is doesn't have anything to do with this. The OP wants the text to go to the next line, not shrinking the text.

Comment: but i programmetically created label in table view cell

Comment: please refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685735/how-can-i-make-text-in-a-uilabel-shrink-font-size

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest two options,

- Use this method to find the required height for your text label and
  set it to that:

`CGFloat height = [foodspe sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(food_lbl.frame.size.width, 500) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;`

- Add a space between each word of your input text. That is change this `paneer,panjabi,pasta,pizza,Puff,chocolates` to `paneer, panjabi, pasta, pizza, Puff, chocolates`

Comment: ya,your answer is right..But my label is dinamically created text so i cant add space between them.

Answer (score 0):

if your listed code (shown below) was used exactly in your project, then you are adding a wrong label.

```
UILabel *food_lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
...
[cell.contentView addSubview:header];
```

You are adding **header** rather than the newly created **food_lbl**.

Comment: it's possibly a typing mistake. He said word is not wrapping in the label. So it's displaying on the screen.